# Non linear ODE with constraint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE

$$u' = \bar{u}^2, u(0) = u_0, \quad {\rm Im}(u^3) = c,$$ where 
$u: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $c$ is a real given constant. 
I'm looking for an explicit formula for the solution !

I tried the following: Using the equation, we can write
$$\bar u 'u - u'\bar u = u^3 - \bar u^3 = \frac 12 ic.$$ 
Hence, writing $u = re^{i\theta},$ we find 
$$r(r'+ i \theta ' r)- r(r'-i\theta ' r) =  \frac 12 ic,$$ which implies that $$\theta'r^2 = \frac 14 c.$$
On the other hand, form the given constraint, we get $$r^3 \sin(3\theta) = c.$$
Thank you for any further hint.

Answer (score 1):

You already found $\quad r^3\sin(3\theta)=c$

HINT :

$$\sin(3\theta)=\frac{c}{r^3} \quad \text{and}\quad \cos(3\theta)=\left(1-\frac{c^2}{r^6}\right)^{1/2}$$
$$u^3=r^3\left(\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta)\right)=r^3\cos(3\theta)+ic$$
$$u^3=r^3\left(1-\frac{c^2}{r^6}\right)^{1/2}+ic $$
$$u^3=\left(r^6-c^2\right)^{1/2}+ic \tag 1$$
$$(u^3)'=\frac{3r^5\:r'}{\left(r^6-c^2\right)^{1/2}}$$
$u' = \bar{u}^2$

$ u^2u' = u^2\bar{u}^2 = r^4$

$\frac13 (u^3)' = r^2$

$$\frac13\frac{3r^5\:r'}{\left(r^6-c^2\right)^{1/2}}=r^4$$
$$r'=\frac{\left(r^6-c^2\right)^{1/2}}{r}$$
This is a separable ODE formally solvable in terms of elliptic functions.

So, you get $r$, then $u^3$ from Eq.$(1)$ from which $u$ can be formally derived.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, using, the elliptic functions to integrate   $r/(r^6- c^2)^{1/2}$ define $t\mapsto r(t)$ implicitly !

Comment: Yes.  When I wrote that the solution can be FORMALLY derived, I mean that we have to use formal symbols, i.e. the symbol of inverse function $r(t)=t^{-1}(r)$ in the "explicite" form of solution. Alternatively, the solution can be express on parametric form : $$\begin{cases} u=u(r)\\ t=t(r)\end{cases}$$

Comment: Would it be better if we write $u = x + iy$ and work on the system 
$$x' = x^2 -y^2, y' = -2xy ? $$

Comment: You can try it. Good luck.